# Square root not diving properly

Tags: c

I've created a program which takes an integer x input, then loops until x is met while also taking other integer inputs. I then do various calculations, and then find a square root of a certain value. When I divide by square root however I get a 0 when I know I should be getting a different value as the maths doesn't add up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>  

int main(void) {

    int multiply1, multiply2, add, squareRoot;
    int i;
    int n;
    int x;
    int s;
    double divide, test = 0;

    scanf("%d", &x);

    for (s = 0; s < x; s++) {
        scanf("%d %d", &i ,&n);
    }

    multiply1 = i * i;
    multiply2 = n * n;

    add = multiply1 + multiply2;

    squareRoot = sqrt(add);
    printf("%d", i);
    test = (i / squareRoot);

    printf("Multiplication = %d\n", multiply1);
    printf("Multiplication = %d\n", multiply2);
    printf("Added together = %d\n", add);
    printf("square root = %d\n", squareRoot);
    printf("First output = %.3f\n", test);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's because `i` is an `int` variable, google *integer division* and you might understand why.

Comment: Along with that, `squareRoot` should also probably be a double. Unless you know `i^2 + n^2` will always be a perfect square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dividing two integers so the actual division returns the result rounded down. You should instead cast to double and then divide.

```
test = ((double)i/squareRoot);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do,

1. Without changing your program, simply cast the `i` and `squareRoot` variables to `double`

   ```
   test = (double) i / (double) squareRoot;
   ```
2. Change your program and make `i` and `squareRoot` a `double`.

I, would choose *2* because `sqrt()` returns a `double` and that might cause an integer overflow.

Comment: Not necessary to cast both `i` and `squareRoot` to double; casting either one of them will guarantee that the math is done as a double.

Comment: @FredK I know, I just do it like that because then it will be clear that `squareRoot` is not a `double`, just for readability.